# Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Operation timed out #60]

Tags: php, laravel, gmail, laravel-5

I can't sent out any email in my local environment.

I keep getting :

[image]
_

## .env file.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=my-email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
```

---

**Note** : Surprisingly - I have the same setting in my production server, and it works perfectly.

Any hints / suggestions ?

Comment: I am not sure but, could a 2-factor authentication from Gmail affecting this? you should go to Gmail settings and find out if it is indeed the problem!! just a guess.

Comment: What is 2-factor authentication  ? and how do I fix it ? Like I mentioned, I've been using my application for almost a month, and nothing wrong with it. I'm very curious.

Comment: I didn't mean to confuse you. But as you said it has just been month, then it could be some other problem. But any way, if 2-factor authentication enabled in gmail setting , after you login to your gmail account, google sends OTP to your mobile number. you need to enter correct OTP to see your emails.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Update my driver line to

## `MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail`

It works on the first try.

Final `.env` file should look like this

```
MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=my-email@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*****
```

Comment: this is wrong answer. It will send email through default server smtp not using gmail smtp.

Comment: This does not answer the question. `MAIL_DRIVER=smtp`

Comment: Some time this work some time Not.  This Solution DOes nto work With SMTP

Answer (score 2):

For me the following worked with GMAIL:

```
'encryption' => 'ssl',
```

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

1: Either you must allow less secure apps or use app password by enabling 2 step verification on your gmail acc.
2: Disable any antivirus on your machine.

Answer (score 0):

Change setting in .env file and keep your mail server's credentials after setup of smtp

`MAIL_DRIVER=smtp 
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com 
MAIL_PORT=465 
MAIL_USERNAME=xxx 
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxx`

Answer (score -1):

Laravel also includes drivers for the Mailgun and Mandrill HTTP APIs. These APIs are often simpler and quicker than the SMTP servers. Both of these drivers require that the Guzzle 5 HTTP library be installed into your application. You can add Guzzle 5 to your project by adding the following line to your composer.json file:

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.0"

composer update
```

**Mailgun Driver**

To use the Mailgun driver, set the driver option to mailgun in your config/mail.php configuration file. Next, create an config/services.php configuration file if one does not already exist for your project. Verify that it contains the following options:

```
'mailgun' => [
    'domain' => 'your-mailgun-domain',
    'secret' => 'your-mailgun-key',
],
```

**Mandrill Driver**

To use the Mandrill driver, set the driver option to mandrill in your config/mail.php configuration file. Next, create an config/services.php configuration file if one does not already exist for your project. Verify that it contains the following options:

```
'mandrill' => [
    'secret' => 'your-mandrill-key',
],
```

**Basic Usage**

```
The Mail::send method may be used to send an e-mail message:

Mail::send('emails.welcome', ['key' => 'value'], function($message)
{
    $message->to('foo@example.com', 'John Smith')->subject('Welcome!');
});
```

http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/mail

Comment: I'm not intentionally to use mail gun driver. I want to use my own gmail.

Comment: this does not answer the question.

Comment: This does not answer, but it will helps people who need Mailgun or Mandrill driver.