# Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io

Tags: php, html, laravel, email

I am trying to send a message to an email using smtp.mailtrap.io in Laravel. I have followed a youtube tutorial and keep getting the following error.

> **Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io**

I have attached my code below for this.

PagesController

```
    <?php 

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Post;
use Mail;
use Session;

class PagesController extends Controller {

public function getIndex() {
$posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(4)->get();
return view('welcome')->withPosts($posts);
}

public function getAbout() {
$first = 'Niamh';
$last = 'Flannery';

$fullname = $first . " " . $last;
$email = 'niamh3516@hotmail.co.uk';
$data = [];
$data['email'] = $email;
$data['fullname'] = $fullname;
return view('pages.about')->withData($data);
}

public function getContact() {
return view('contact');
}

public function postContact(Request $request) {
$this->validate($request, [
'email' => 'required|email',
'subject' => 'min:3',
'message' => 'min:10']);

$data = array(
'email' => $request->email,
'subject' => $request->subject,
'bodyMessage' => $request->message
);

Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
$message->from($data['email']);
$message->to('niamh3516@hotmail.co.uk');
$message->subject($data['subject']);
});

Session::flash('success', 'Your Email was Sent!');

return redirect('/');
}


}
```

Contact.blade.php

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1>Contact Me</h1>
            <hr>
            <form action="{{ url('contact') }}" method="POST">
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label name="email">Email:</label>
                    <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label name="subject">Subject:</label>
                    <input id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label name="message">Message:</label>
                    <textarea id="message" name="message" class="form-control">Type your message here...</textarea>
                </div>

                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-success">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('contact', 'PagesController@getContact');

Route::post('contact', 'PagesController@postContact');
```

contact.php

```
<h3> You have a new contact via the contact form </h3>

<div>

{{$bodyMessage}}

</div>

<p> Sent Via {{$email}}</p>
```

.env

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io

MAIL_PORT=25

MAIL_USERNAME=c388d55897e620

MAIL_PASSWORD=f3d7fa90a9c6ab

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: check your `port` some use SSL for SMTP  something like `465` if I remember right.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix The port on my Mailtrap account says to use either 25 or 465 or 2525 should I try all these to see?

Comment: Couldn't hurt, you also have to make sure that the port is open in your firewall for outbound traffic.  There can be many reasons mail doesn't work.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix tried changing the ports and they all returned the same error as above. Checked my firewall it was turned off so I've turned it on but still getting the same error

Comment: Does [it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624194/connection-could-not-be-established-with-host-smtp-gmail-com-operation-timed-ou) help ?

Comment: did you manage to get this working? i'm having the same issue

Answer (score 11):

Use the following settings your .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=c388d55897e620
MAIL_PASSWORD=f3d7fa90a9c6ab
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

And in your config/mail.php add this at the bottom

```
'stream' => [
      'ssl' => [
          'allow_self_signed' => true,
          'verify_peer' => false,
          'verify_peer_name' => false,
      ],
    ],
```

and check if this is correct

```
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

Make sure ssl and smtp are enabled and properly configured on your localhost(check your php.ini)

Comment: where can I find the php.ini file?

Comment: I'm not sure which localhost you are using but it should be in the php folder. For example if you are using xampp it should be in your xampp/php/php.ini

Comment: did you manage to get this working? i'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the project from your Cpanel trying to use port **465** as priority among other ports provide by mailtrap, while running locally use 2525.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a problem with SELinux (CentOS 7), this helped:

```
sudo semanage port -a -t http_port_t -p tcp 2525
```

If it's still not working checking this:

```
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail 1
sudo setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Answer (score -2):

Run the command: `php artisan optimize`.